# A variant of Viète's formula (the 2's replaced by 3's)

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, nested-radicals

I am wondering whether there exists an easy way to evaluate the following infinite product :

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}}}...$

or even better (assuming convergence) of :

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}}}...$

with $a>0.$

This is a variant of Viète's formula :

$V_{\infty}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}.\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}...=\frac{2}{\pi}$

which is much easier to prove since we can define :

$u_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1+u_n}{2}}$ and realise that for $|u_0|<1$ we can also define $cos(\theta)=u_0$.
Viète's formula is just $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n$, which can be easily evaluated using trigonometric identities, especially $cos(2\theta)=2cos²(\theta)-1$ which yields : $cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1+cos(\theta)}{2}}$

So $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}cos(\frac{\theta}{2^n})$
Then using $sin(2\theta)=2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$ mass cancellation occurs and we find $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n=\frac{sin(\theta)}{\theta}.$ Viète's formula corresponds to $u_0=0$, so $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. By replacing with this value, we find Viète's value.

Unfortunately, this strategy doesn't seem to work when the 2's are replaced by something else (like 3 for example) (or at least, I can't find any tractable trigonometric formulas to help) Any idea ? Thank you !

(P.S. : I am very aware that Viète did not use this strategy to find this formula. He used geometry arguments I do not know, so perhaps there is a way to generalize using geometry, although I'd rather have a proof using only analysis...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does this problem come from? Anyway, for $a>0$, let $u_0^{(a)} = 0$ and $u_{n+1}^{(a)} = \sqrt{\frac{1+u_n^{(a)}}{a}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sqrt{\frac{1+u_n^{(a)}}{2}}$. We wish to determine $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n^{(a)}$. Repeating the trigonometric substitutions in your post, we find
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n^{(a)} = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \right)^n $$
For $0<a<2$ this diverges, for $a=2$ it equals $2/\pi$ and for $a>2$ it equals $0$.

Comment: Hmm... I should have thought about it, for some reasons I kept trying to find a new trigonometric formula with a 3 instead of a 2... This problem is pretty well-known, there is a wikipedia article about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula

Comment: Don't worry about it! If it weren't for your question, I wouldn't know about this formula :)

Comment: @Evariste Feel free to expand the wikipedia article with a discussion of the general problem that you proposed.

Comment: I don't think it's worth it, I've never felt dumber, even though I'm still glad to know about  the completely unexpected behaviour of this problem with the variation of a. Thanks a lot though

Comment: Okay, no problem.